# Logic broken when reaching last data

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to count the redundant of the data in each row in the same column when hit the button. It will sort the data fist and will count and show how many times of that word repeated in that column. But when it reach to the last word, it wont count and show how many redundant of that word. This is my code

```
Dim start As Integer
Dim last As Integer
Dim word As String
Dim line As Integer
Dim count As Integer

line = 5
count = 1

With Columns("A")
    .Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas).Activate
    start = ActiveCell.Row
    last = ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row
End With

Range(Cells(start, 1), Cells(last, 1)).Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

For i = start To last
    word = Cells(i, 1).Value
    Cells(line, 6) = word
    For j = i + 1 To last
        If Cells(j, 1).Value = word Then
            count = count + 1
        Else
            Cells(line, 7) = count
            line = line + 1
            count = 1
        End If
        Exit For
    Next j
Next i
```

I am new for vba. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use `COUNTIF`?

Comment: You should have a deeper look into [WorksheetFunction.CountIf method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.countif) that should be a way faster that using a loop to count. If you use formulas you don't even need to write VBA code for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the logic flaw is in that `Exit For` which defeats the purpose of the loop

```
For j = i + 1 To last
    If Cells(j, 1).Value = word Then
        count = count + 1
    Else
        Cells(line, 7) = count
        line = line + 1
        count = 1
    End If
    Exit For '<--- this will always makes the loop exit after first iteration
Next j
```

hence you should eliminate the loop and run the check for its first iteration only

```
If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = word Then
    count = count + 1
Else
    Cells(line, 7) = count
    line = line + 1
    count = 1
End If
```

Comment: You are welcome. Then if you mark the answer as accepted it'd direct future readers, too...